# python convert string to datetime which is django time format

Tags: python

time = "2019-02-20T04:35:48.679000+00:00"

```
>>> import datetime
>>> 
>>> date_time_str = "2019-02-20T04:35:48.679000+00:00"
>>> date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/_strptime.py", line 510, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/_strptime.py", line 343, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '2019-02-20T04:35:48.679000+00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'
```

The time is Django format time. Unfortunately i am storing the same in an CharField()
so it is giving time as a string while fetching data from database.

How can i convert it into actual time.

Answer (score 3):

You need to account for the 'T', and I don't know how to match the "+00:00" part unless it's simply a literal that's always that value. So this works:

```
import datetime
date_time_str = "2019-02-20T04:35:48.679000+00:00"
date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f+00:00')
```

Comment: Ok, I admit it...@Mike's answer is what you want :) . ... unless you don't want to require python-dateutil for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

try to use python-dateutil

install it `pip install python-dateutil`

and then

```
from dateutil import parser
dt = parser.parse("2019-02-20T04:35:48.679000+00:00")
```

Comment: hi @kiran could you choose one answer you prefer?